# A better random function to select images from folder

Tags: php

I have a folder with at least 5K different images. I added a button on the site called 'random', so when the user click on it random images selected from folder shows.

this is what i have so far.

```
$images = $img_arr[rand(0,count($img_arr)-1)];
```

is there any better way to show better random results. thanks.

Comment: [`array_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) is your friend.

Comment: worth looking at [mt_rand](http://uk3.php.net/mt_rand) instead of `rand()`

Comment: ...plus, `mt_rand()` is faster than `rand()` (sidenote)

Comment: i have to do like this? `$dir_array[mt_rand(0,count($dir_array)-1)];`

Comment: Are they stored in a database? Have you thought of choosing the random images in the sql query?

Comment: @Pjack no are not stored in database . the images are in folder.

Comment: who is much faster `rand`, `array_rand` or `mt_rand` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [array_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), or [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and pick first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rand_key = array_rand($img_arr);
$image = $img_arr[$rand_key];
unset($img_arr[$rand_key];)
```

Or with mt_rand:

```
$rand_key = mt_rand(0,count($img_arr)-1)
$image = $img_arr[$rand_key];
unset($img_arr[$rand_key]);
```

This way you remove the image you picked from the array.

Comment: Why to remove the image from array? i dont understand, if i remove no image will show.

Comment: So your image won't be picked twice. But you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mcrypt`:

```
<?php
$bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$unpack = unpack("Nint", $bytes);
$val = $unpack['int'] & 0x7FFFFFFF;

$images = $img_arr[($val % (count($img_arr) - 1))];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but how to implement your code with this `$images = $img_arr[rand(0,count($img_arr)-1)];`